# Open html file dialog with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to open input file dialog after clicking on link. I made a script with jquery. But I also want to avoid opening this dialog after clicking on input file:

```
            $('#link').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#id_default_image').click();
            });
            $('.file_input').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
```

Now when I click on link or input file dialog does not show. Can I check if user clicks on link or on input and show dialog or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use global flag for this, and raise it when clicking the link.

Code will now be:

```
$('#link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window["link_clicked"] = true;
    $('#id_default_image').click();
    window["link_clicked"] = false;     
});
```

And to check the flag:

```
$('.file_input').click(function(event) {
    if (window["link_clicked"]) {
        alert("you clicked the link");
    }
    //event.preventDefault();
});
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/trG5D/1/